# Extract text from PDF using .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, .net-standard

I'm currently using iTextSharp 5.X to do the job, but I would like to migrate the my app and its libraries to use .NET Standard.

Is there a port of itextsharp or another library to do the task? (preferably free)

Comment: Docotic.Pdf Library (https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) is not free, but can extract text. Supports .NET Standard. You can keep you source code private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText 7 for .NET is available for .NET Standard, see NuGet.org.

iText and iTextSharp are free under the AGPL license if you publish the source code of your own software, also under the AGPL license.

For now, there is a different package for .NET Framework (version `7.0.4`) and .NET standard (version `7.0.4-netstandard`). We hope to have a combined package for the next release.

Comment: Can you, please, point the exact NuGet package that is compatible with .NET Standard? The one I found targets .NET Framework 4.X (https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/)

Comment: You need that exact package, with the exact version "7.0.4-netstandard".